# World Cup Sweepstakes

Tags: probability

Scenario: A sweepstake in the workplace for the World Cup.

Everybody wants to draw Brazil in the secret draw.

It is decided as there are 16 of us we will put the favourite top 16 teams in the hat.

Therefore the chances of me drawing Brazil from the hat are 1 in 16.

My question: When one person draws a team from the hat before me, and I go next, are the odds for me still 1 in 16, even though I only have 15 to choose from?

Comment: Welcome to mathSE! what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Your odds are still 1 in 16 if you don't pay attention to whether the first person picks Brazil.  If you know that the first person did not pick Brazil, your odds have improved to 1 in 15.  If you know the first person did pick Brazil, your odds have decreased to zero.

You can even do the calculation:  Chance you get Brazil = (chance first person got Brazil)(your new odds) + (chance first person did not get Brazil)(your new odds in that case)=$\frac 1{16} \cdot 0 + \frac {15}{16}\cdot \frac 1{15}=\frac 1{16}$  Math works!

Comment: And if the first person did pick Brazil, your chances have decreased to 0. ;)